# Depart UK by Air or Ship?

Tags: transit, uk, us-citizens, thai-citizens

(Taken from the UK Immigration website)

> You might be eligible for ‘transit without visa’ if: you arrive and depart by air have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive and "have the correct documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country)

Two passengers,  One a US passport holder and one from Thailand with a valid USA Visa, will be arriving from Bangkok by air but are departing Heathrow to the UK Southampton Pier on the same day for a direct transatlantic Cunard Cruise to the USA

Would this situation suffice for a Heathrow to Southampton Pier "Transit without a visa: and allow air travel to Heathrow without a UK visa?

Comment: Would you care to add the link you are quoting from?

Comment: The cruise line you are booked with deals with this issue every week. They are almost certainly going to be able to give you good information.

Comment: Odd, but I tried them two times and they never heard of this problem before.  Actually they didn't seem to know anything bout UK Transit visas

Answer (score 13):

There's not much to misunderstand in the text you quote, is there? Transit-witout-visa is only available if you arrive **and** depart by air, which you don't.

The American is visa-free for to the UK in any case, and so doesn't need a visa anyway.

The Thai will need to apply for a *Visitor in Transit* visa in advance.